# Improve video quality using ffmpeg

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg to improve video quality, I downloaded video 360x240 resolution and trying to convert it to 720x480. I tried so many commands with ffmpeg with this one. what i am doing wrong? it increases the video size but video quality is still as before conversion

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -y -vf scale=-1:480 test.mp4
```

Comment: You can't increase video quality.

Comment: Conversion is used to reduce the video size(redundant information) without of course losing the original quality, what you are trying to do is the inverse.